# Why is "threshold" pronounced "thresh-hold"?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

Why is [*threshold* pronounced "thresh-hold"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvfFBhPtcLk)?

Comment: Usually it isn't, though the difference is minimal unless someone speaks very slowly. But my pronunciation would not include an extra "h".

Comment: In my accent I certainly do pronounce an extra "h". Perhaps the question is in which accents do speakers pronounce the word "threshold" with an extra h? New York / Brooklyn accent speaking here.

Comment: I think you have it backwards, since speech is primary. And there can seldom be an answer as to why we spell things as we do.

Comment: To make clear that it's there to "hold" the "thresh" :)

Comment: It looks like a compound word. *"thresh"* + *"hold"*. So some people pronounce it like that. (Etymologically, it appears that it's *thresh* + something, but nobody is sure what the something is.)

Comment: I've always pronounced it "Thresh-hold" because that's how we were taught. But when you look at the spelling, it makes no sense to pronounce it that way. Why would so many people mispronounce it? The only reason I can think of is that pronouncing it as "Threshold" _sounds_ wrong.

Comment: Spike: Are you expecting it to be pronounced 'thress- hold'? As @tchrist said, language is first what is spoken, then later what is written. Spelling is a poor representation for spoken language; it is an attempt to record speech. Speech isn't an attempt to represent written words.

Comment: @mitch I think he's referring to thresh-old vs. thresh-hold.

Comment: @DavidM that's correct. That's what I was referring to.

Comment: @DavidM: Oh. Right. Makes sense. But then Spike can you edit your question to make that clear (it's not enough to leave it in comments)

Comment: @Sure thing Mitch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If people are pronouncing it that way, it might be one example of the spread of *literal pronunciation* in the last few decades. This is a trend where, contrary to traditional practice, people are pronouncing certain words as if every syllable needs its proper exposure.

One example is *accent* which until very recently would be pronounced *acc'nt* - that is, with the second syllable unstressed, a nothing-syllable, the way we (still) pronounce *decent*. But nowadays it's more commonly heard as a *spondee*, which is the technical name for a word with two equally stressed syllables. So it comes out almost as if it's two separate words, *ax* and *ent*.

More examples:

*Philharmonic*. Radio announcers traditionally suppressed the "h" in what is an unstressed syllable: *philermonic*. But now, as often as not, it's restored: *phil-harmonic*, as if it's two words.

*Tortoise*: traditionally *tortus*, increasingly *tortoyse*. Because, presumably, it accords with the way it's spelt. So, like *accent*, it's turning into a word with two equally stressed syllables, a spondee.

*Maidstone*. The traditional pronunciation, *Maidst'n*, still holds sway (I think), but increasingly *Maid-stone* is being heard.

So it might be that *thresh-hold* is a symptom of the same thing. The word's spelling is derived from two words joined together, but the second "h" is missing, probably because that reflected the standard pronunciation of former times: *thresh'ld*. But if you restore it in the spoken word, you're actually pronouncing a letter that isn't there.

Comment: Aw come on, you’ve got to be kidding about the *tortoise*: it mustn’t rhyme with *turquoise* but with *porpoise*.

Comment: @tchrist: Not the best example, I have heard *porpoise* pronounced *poor poise* rather than *porpus*.

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot about *porpoise*. That too.

Comment: @TimLymington Those people should be identified before they are allowed to mate …

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Terpsichore, I think I should be alright to rest now. I couldn't sleep because I just kept thinking, "Why would we pronounce a letter that isn't there?" and, "Why would we leave out a letter that we actually pronounce?" Anyway, I'm glad that Threshold is spelled and often pronounced the way it is. I just couldn't figure out why.

Comment: The word ***not*** derived from *thresh* + *hold*; it just looks like it is.

Answer (score 1):

German s is never pronounced as 'sh' it's mostly the 'z' sound in English, except for end of syllable, when it's pronounced 's'. Only ss or ß are always pronounced as 's', whereby ss shortens the vowel while ß does not.
Here the ethymology of threshold:
Old English þrescold, þærscwold, þerxold, etc., "door-sill, point of entering," a word of uncertain origin and probably much altered by folk-etymology.

The first element probably is related to Old English þrescan (see thresh), either in its current sense of "thresh" or with its original sense of "to tread, trample." The second element has been much transformed in all the Germanic languages, suggesting its literal sense was lost even in ancient times. In English it probably has been altered to conform to hold.

Liberman (Oxford University Press blog, Feb. 11, 2015) revives an old theory that the second element is the Proto-Germanic instrumental suffix *-thlo and the original sense of threshold was a threshing area adjacent to the living area of a house. Cognates of the compound include Old Norse þreskjoldr, Swedish tröskel, Old High German driscufli, German dialectal drischaufel. The figurative use was present in Old English.

Comment: In many accents of German (including the one typically taught to English speakers), the letter "s" represents /ʃ/ ("sh") in syllables starting with "st-" and "sp-", except for in some loanwords. E.g. *der Stein, das Spiel.* This is thought to perhaps be a remnant of an earlier distinction between between laminal and apical sibilants, with the original "s" sounds being apical and the "z" sounds (both the affricate and the fricative that is currently spelled as ss/ß) derived from assibilation of t being laminal.

Comment: The pronunciation of "s" as /ʃ/ when it is written in combination with "t" or "p" is not a dialect thing, but the proper pronunciation in German language. Only some northern German dialects stick to "s" even in this cases. 
For example, the proper pronunciation of "Stein" is [ʃtaɪ̯n] in IPA.

Answer (score 1):

As I would hear and pronounce the word "*threshold*", its transcription was `[ˈtres-(h)old]` or even more commonly `[ˈtres-(h)olt]` due to the last consonant sound being assimilated. Pronouncing this word as `[ˈtreʃ-old]` (or `[ˈtreʃ-olt]`) seems (or might it be more appropriate to say "sounds") nonsense for me.

As it was mentioned in some earlier posts and comments to them, "*threshold*" is derived from the Old English "*therscold*" or "*threscold*". And this takes its roots from Old German "*Drischaufel*" `[ˈdrɪʃ-aʊ-fel]`, which DOES have `[ʃ]` in its transcription. But Old English is a north-western dialect of Old German, in which most of `[ʃ]` sounds used to turn into `[s]` ones. So transcription for "*therscold*", for sure, was `[ˈt(h)ers-kolt]`.

Comment: This would benefit from a citation.  Do stick around and take the [tour], and welcome to EL&U.

Comment: [This website](https://people.umass.edu/sharris/in/gram/GrammarBook/Pronunciation.html) says that *sc* was always pronounced /ʃ/ in Old English. Why do you think it was pronounced /sk/ in *þrescold*?

Comment: @PeterShor, I think it was a compound word of type *þres-uold* and if *s* and *h* are separate, there is no digraph and pronunciation should be /sk/, which transforms into /s(h)/ later.

Answer (score 0):

There was never a second "h" in **threshold**. From OED

> Etymology: Old English þerscold , -wold , þerxold , -wold , þrexold, -wold = Old Norse þreskjǫldr , - […]The first element is generally identified with **thresh** v. (? in its original sense ‘to tread, trample’), the forms of which it generally follows; but the second is doubtful, and has in English, as in other [related] languages, undergone many popular transformations.

Answer (score -2):

This word is derived from old German.  In the German alphabet the letter s is pronounced with a "sh" sound, and a double s is pronounced "es".  The double s in German is ß and sounds like our English s.  That having been said, the word gets pronounced thresh-hold and not thres-hold.

Comment: Well, what about the *s* in *lesen*? That's not pronounced with a "sh" sound. And there are verbs like *essen* which don't normally use the ß except in some inflections.

Comment: @plasmasnakeneo that is Hungarian where the letter s is pronounced with a "sh" sound, not German (except in some cases).