# Words like "threshold"?

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology

Threshold is pronounced like "thresh-hold" [as noted in this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161655/why-is-threshold-pronounced-thresh-hold), however, what is interesting is that there is only one *h* in the word, and it serves two phonetic roles (being part of *sh* and as a regular *h*). This is different from words such as withhold, which have a separate h for the *th* and *h* sounds. While I suspect that this is due to a mixture of etymology (as threshold comes from the middle English "thresshold" according to Merriam-Webster) and pronunciation (the *h* sound in threshold is unstressed), I am not sure.

My question is: are there any similar words in English (i.e. words that have one letter serve as two phonemes)?

Comment: How do you mean the h is unstressed? Consonants cannot receive stress in English (or nearly any other language in the world), so I'm guessing stress if not what you're really trying to refer to… but I can't figure out what you _are_ trying to refer to.

Comment: You mean like "eighteen"? Could be a long list - are list questions on topic?

Comment: @David: I assume from your question that you are one of the people who pronounce a double (or long) /t/ in that word. Many people do not, including me.

Comment: An example of a single letter that corresponds or is ostensibly meant to represent more than one morpheme: the t in _eighth_ (and _height(h)_ if you're one of those who pronounce it with a final th sound). Kind of related or similar is how the i in _Maria_ and _Mariah_ are pronounced differently, even though it's the same name. (Edit: David and Colin got there with almost the same example while I was typing and trying to think of other examples.)

Comment: @ColinFine Do you really say 'eight-een'? I had not imagined you with a cockney accent?

Comment: @ColinFine - I don't think I am, actually. :) (One of "those" people, I mean.) It's just that "eighteen" has what I would think of as a double-duty consonant, on the analogy of OP's example. Cf. OED etymology: "Old English _e(a)htatýne_ , _-téne_ , corresponds to Old Frisian _achtatîne_ , Old Saxon _ahtotian_ , _ahtetehan_ (Dutch _achttien_ ), Old High German _ahtozehan_,... Old Norse _áttján_ ..., Gothic _\*ahtau-taíhun_ ; < Old Germanic _\*ahtau_ , _ahtô_ , eight adj. and n. + _\*tehun_ ten adj., n., and adv.; for the divergent English form of the second element, see -teen comb. form."

Comment: @WS2: No, I say "eigh-teen" (the /t/ is aspirated, showing that it is in the onset).

Comment: It is surprising that threshold is spelled in this way, especially when one considers the origin of the term. I believe it goes back to the practice of laying straw (thresh) on the floor. The threshold was the bar which held it in place, and kept it in the house. thus one would have expected 'thresh-hold'.

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about letters, not sounds. Historically there were certainly two /t/, one in each syllable; and some people still pronounce them that way. But for people who pronounce it as I do, the letter notes only one consonant.

Comment: Looking up _threshold_ in the OED, the second element of the word never had an /h/ until Middle English, and even then it was as often _wold_, _fold_ or other possibilities. It seems to me that the /h/ arose from either folk-etymology on the second element, or the 'h' in the spelling.

Comment: @ColinFine Right, eigh-teen. Yes I think that's how I say it too, 'Eigh-een' would be cockney, wouldn't it!

Comment: @WS2: I don't know if we're being influenced by the fact that "hypothetically" there are actually *two* /t/'s in *eighteen*, but  it seems to me most "Estuary English" speakers probably *would* enunciate one. We are actually *capable* of doing this, stereotypes notwithstanding (unlike the French, most of whom find it extremely difficult if not impossible to enunciate a leading aspirated /h/ :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers But cockneys don't enunciate any t. 'Eigh-een', 'Fow-een' for fourteen.

Comment: @WS2: Ahem. I said ***we*** there because to all intents and purposes, I'm a Cockney myself (all that claptrap about being born within the sound of Bow Bells notwithstanding). Sure, 'eigh ʔ een' will be used *sometimes*, but I have the definite feeling the glottal stop is far less likely there than in, for example, 'wa ʔ er' (water).

Comment: Good question, bad example. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/pronounce/american_english/threshold

Comment: You might be looking for the concept of [ambisyllabicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable#Syllable_division_and_ambisyllabicity).

Answer (score 2):

Some Modern English spellings (15th century on) include:

*threshould, thressald, threszshold, tresholde, thresholde, threshold, threskwolde,  thresh-fod, thressholl, threshal, threshel, thrashel, drashel, thressholl, treshwart, threshwort, threshut* and most interestingly *freshwood* (this last suggesting either a separate term that merged or an even more interesting possibility a folk-etymology pushing the word into a new direction).

I'm not even going to touch on the Middle English and Old English forms, beyond noting that they are even more various, and similarly its cognates in other languages are not always obvious.

It's a very old word that has had a variety of both spellings and pronunciations.

We can see in the above alone, some that seem to have no /ʃ/ at all (which in English we most often get from *-sh*) such as *threskwolde*, and some that clearly do, and likewise some that seem to have no /h/ and some that clearly do. Indeed, we've every possible permutation of whether it has /ʃ/ and /h/, /ʃ/ and no /h/, /h/ and no /ʃ/, or neither.

And it remains that /ˈθrɛʃəʊld/ (no h) is listed along with /ˈθrɛʃhəʊld/ as the pronunciation in the OED, with Mirriam Websters giving both too in their way of offering pronuncation guides ("\ˈthresh-ˌhōld, ˈthre-ˌshōld\") and so on.

And there we have it, the word is still found in two pronunciations, one of which matches the single-H spelling perfectly and one that doesn't, and both those pronunciations and the sole spelling that remains in contemporary Modern English come from a much greater variety earlier in the Modern period, which stems from a similar variety prior to that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's interesting the way you put it. Because the 'h' doesn't really take part in two letters at all. "esh" is its own letter, in the IPA and in pronunciation. Orthography and phonetics in English have little in common. But you're right, it was probably originally "thresh-old" and some people today would still pronounce it that way. So, at some point an "h" sound came in to certain group's pronunciations of "esh" before a vowel and thus "thresh-hold".